# How would I keep the rotation of the look of the object but make the rotation 0 Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How would I be able to have Wheel look the same but make the rotation 0.

[image: screenshot of car in unity]

Comment: Rotate the mesh.

Answer (score 1):

As already commented you can rotate the mesh in 3D modeling software.

A faster way would be to parent the GameObject that represents the wheel under another GameObject, which will be acting as a pivot then. Just position it at the exact position of the wheel GameObject, but with a the desired rotation.

Comment: This is how I deal with weird pivots (and most other alignment issues)