# Unity How to change the axis direction of the 3D model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

[image]

[image]

All the 3d models in the project that I'm making follow the axis direction of the first picture, but only the model shown in the second picture has a different axis direction.
As I code for one axis, the movement between the two models is different.

Is there any way to change the axial direction?

Comment: I had this after importing models from certain external tools.  The easiest fix to create a prefab and rotate it in the right direction.  From then on you should use the prefab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I keep the rotation of the look of the object but make the rotation 0 Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639637/how-would-i-keep-the-rotation-of-the-look-of-the-object-but-make-the-rotation-0)

Answer (score 0):

---

Answer based on my comment beneath question

---

I had this after importing models from certain external tools. The easiest fix to create a prefab and rotate it in the right direction. From then on you should use the prefab.